# re.sub w/ substring ending with different numbers

Tags: python, regex

Have a bunch of variable labels that I am trying to clean up.

Each string starts with a Question number such as "Q1_1 - How old are you?"

I want to remove everything before the beginning of the question.

input: `"Q1_1 - How old are you?"`

output: `"How old are you?"`

New to using `re.sub` and understand how to use it on a case by case, but for 40+ variables all at once I am at a loss and couldn't find anything online that worked.

Found this code online and it just replaced the character from '_' to '-':

```
re.sub('/.*- / ','',myvarlabel)
```

Comment: Why regex? `s.split('-')[1].strip()` (assuming question does not contain `-`).

Comment: @Austin The question can contain `-` if you simply add the `maxsplit=1` argument to the `split` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern uses a greedy quantifier for the dot `.*` which can lead to a broad match.

If each string starts with your pattern, you could also use an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string.

For your example string, you could get a more precise match using this pattern and then replace with an empty string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4z1hkP/5) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ysf3hy)

```
^Q\d+[a-zA-Z0-9]*_[a-zA-Z0-9]+ +- +
```

That will match

- `^` Start of string
- `Q\d+` Match Q followed by 1+ digits
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` Match any listed in the character class 0+ times
- `_[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match underscore, match any listed in the character class 1+ times
- `+- +` Match 1+ times a space, hyphen, 1+ times a space

Note: Instead of a space, you might use `\s` but note that would also match a newline.

For example:

```
re.sub(r"^Q\d+[a-zA-Z0-9]*_[a-zA-Z0-9]+ +- +", "", "Q1_1 - How old are you?")
```

Or use a negated character class to get a broader match:

```
^Q\d+[^_]*_\S+ +- +
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4z1hkP/4)

Comment: What if the Q may also include letters. For instance Q1a_M.

Comment: @Stretch You could use a character class and add to it what you would allow to match [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4z1hkP/2)

Comment: @Stretch You can also extend the character class using a quantifier https://regex101.com/r/4z1hkP/3 I have added an update to my answer.

Comment: Q6b1_TN - How old are you?  Won't work on this example.

Comment: @Stretch You can get a broader match using https://regex101.com/r/4z1hkP/4 or also add matching digits to the first character class https://regex101.com/r/4z1hkP/5

Comment: @Stretch I have updated my answer with the latest 2 patterns.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os

s = 'Q1_1 - How old are you?'
print(re.sub(r'^.*Q\d+_\d+\s-\s','',s))
```

Works for these:

```
IN: Q21_2 - How old are you?
OUT: How old are you?

IN: 123 - Q21_2 - Q21_2 - How old are you?
OUT: How old are you?
```

Will not match this one:

```
IN: Q21_2 : How ol - d are you?
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the question number and `[space]-[space]`, your pattern should be:

```
s = "Q1_1 - How old are you?"

re.sub(r"^Q\d+(_\d+)? +- +", "", s)
```

This will match

- `Q`,
- One or more `digits` 0-9
- An optional one or more `_digit`
- Followed by `-` between spaces

This allows you to match and remove any of the following:

- Q1 -
- Q1_1 -
- Q12 -
- Q12_12 -